# IpcServerChannel properties problem

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-2.0, c#-2.0, ipc

I've got to write a service program and a program to maintain it in C#.  I can't use .net 3 or 4, so I'm stick with .Net 2.0.  I've learn that `IPC` channels could help me but I've got problem using them.

I'm trying to create my `IpcServerChannel` using `IDictionary` as a properties list.  But I can't get to find the good properties to send.

Here's my list

```
IDictionary properties = new Hashtable();

properties.Add("authorizedGroup", "Users");
properties.Add("portName", "ServerChannel");

channel = new IpcServerChannel(properties,null);
```

When trying to run this, I got an `IdentityNotMappedException` error.  Do you guys have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've got something.

The fact is that all information I found about IPC was in English, so it was using the "Users" group.  The computer I'm working on is in French, so the "Users" group is named "Utilisateurs".  I corrected it, and it is now working.

Answer (score 2):

The user names are dependant on the Windows languange:

You can use the SID code of the Account and also the Sid constants. For example "WellKnownSidType.WorldSid" is the same as "EveryOne".

```
// Get SID code for the EveryOne user
SecurityIdentifier sid = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null);
// Get the NT account related to the SID
NTAccount account = sid.Translate(typeof(NTAccount)) as NTAccount;

// Put the account locale name to the properties
properties.Add("authorizedGroup", account.Value);
```